# MVC 3 with Entity Framework CodeFirst approach does not save and retrieve the Foreign Key object

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3, ef-code-first

I am fairly new to both MVC and Entity Framework. I did some reading on both and decided to use Entity Framework Code First Approach as I am building an application from scratch. I am build an intranet Ticket management system. the Model Looks like this:

```
    public class TicketsInfo
{
    [Key,DatabaseGenerate(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int TicketID { get; set; }
    public  string TicketDescription { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("category")]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public virtual Category category { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("AssignedTo")]
    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
    public virtual Department AssignedTo { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("status")]
    public int StatusId { get; set; }
    public virtual Status status { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("OPS_Priority")]
    public int OPSPriorityId { get; set; }
    public virtual OPSPriority OPS_Priority { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("TISMIS_Priority")]
    public int TISMISPriorityId { get; set; }
    public virtual TISMISPriority TISMIS_Priority { get; set; }
    [Timestamp,DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime DateRequestedby_OPS { get; set; }
    [Timestamp, DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime DateApprovedby_TISMIS { get; set; }
    [Timestamp, DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime ETC_OPS { get; set; }
    [Timestamp, DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime ETC_TISMIS { get; set; }
    [Timestamp, DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime CompletionDate { get; set; }
    [Timestamp, DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime ClosedDate { get; set; }
    [Timestamp, DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime ReOpenDate { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("requestor")]
    public int RequestorId { get; set; }
    public virtual Requestor requestor { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("assignor")]
    public int AssignorId { get; set; }
    public virtual Assignor assignor { get; set; }

    public TicketsInfo()
    {
        status=new Status();
        category = new Category();
        AssignedTo=new Department();
        OPS_Priority=new OPSPriority();
        TISMIS_Priority=new TISMISPriority();
        assignor = new Assignor();
        requestor = new Requestor();
    }

}
public class Category
{
    [Key]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string CategoryType { get; set; }

}
public class UserInfo
{
    [Key]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

}
public class Department
{
    [Key]
    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public partial class Requestor:UserInfo
{
    public bool requestor { get; set; }
}
public partial class Approver : UserInfo
{
    public bool approver { get; set; }
}
public partial class Assignor : UserInfo
{
    public bool assignor { get; set; }
}
public class Status
{
    [Key]
    public int StatusId { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
}
public class Priority
{
    [Key]
    public int PriorityId { get; set; }

    public string value { get; set; }
}
public class OPSPriority : Priority
{

    public string type { get; set; }
}
public class TISMISPriority : Priority
{

    public string type { get; set; }
}
```

When I used this POCO model class to generate a controller and its related view, it gave automatic Index, Create,Edit and Delete function with views which support dropdownlists with values picked from Category, Priority and so on. I overrided the TicketsContext:DbContext(data context class name) class method Seed with some initial data like this:

```
    public class TicketsContextInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<TicketsContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(TicketsContext context)
    {
        context.Departments.Add(new Department { Name = "OPS" });
        context.Departments.Add(new Department { Name = "TIS-MIS" });

        context.Status.Add(new Status { status = "OPEN" });
        context.Status.Add(new Status { status = "CLOSED" });
        context.Status.Add(new Status { status = "IN PROGRESS" });

        context.TISMISPriorities.Add(new TISMISPriority { PriorityId = 1, type = "1", value = "HIGH" });
        context.TISMISPriorities.Add(new TISMISPriority { PriorityId = 2, type = "1", value = "LOW" });
        context.TISMISPriorities.Add(new TISMISPriority { PriorityId = 3, type = "1", value = "MEDIUM" });

        context.OPSPriorities.Add(new OPSPriority { PriorityId = 1, type = "2", value = "HIGH" });
        context.OPSPriorities.Add(new OPSPriority { PriorityId = 2, type = "2", value = "LOW" });
        context.OPSPriorities.Add(new OPSPriority { PriorityId = 3, type = "2", value = "MEDIUM" });

        context.Categories.Add(new Category {CategoryId=1, CategoryType = "FIR" });
        context.Categories.Add(new Category { CategoryId = 2, CategoryType = "PJR" });

        context.Assignors.Add(new Assignor { UserId = 1, FirstName = "ASCORP\\royjoyde", assignor = true });
        context.Assignors.Add(new Assignor { UserId = 2, FirstName = "ASCORP\\mavanipr", assignor = true });

        context.Requestors.Add(new Requestor  { UserId = 1, FirstName = "ASCORP\\royjoyde", requestor  = true });
        context.Requestors.Add(new Requestor { UserId = 2, FirstName = "ASCORP\\mavanipr", requestor = true });
        base.Seed(context);
    }
}
```

Now I created a new Ticket and saved the data to the local sql server. Quite surprisingly it did not take values from dropdown which were selected, but took values which were created by the context on its own with all fields initialised to null except the ID field which took an autogenerated number. To change this I went to Create function added this piece of Code(The one in Bold):

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(TicketsInfo ticketsinfo)
    {
       // var allUsers=from FirstName in db.Assignors select FirstName;

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            **ticketsinfo.AssignedTo = db.Departments.Find(ticketsinfo.DepartmentId);
            ticketsinfo.status = db.Status.Find(ticketsinfo.StatusId);
            ticketsinfo.category = db.Categories.Find(ticketsinfo.CategoryId);
            ticketsinfo.requestor = db.Requestors.Find(ticketsinfo.RequestorId);
            ticketsinfo.assignor = db.Assignors.Find(ticketsinfo.AssignorId);
            ticketsinfo.OPS_Priority = db.OPSPriorities.Find(ticketsinfo.OPSPriorityId);
            ticketsinfo.TISMIS_Priority = db.TISMISPriorities.Find(ticketsinfo.TISMISPriorityId);**
            db.TicketsInfoes.Add(ticketsinfo);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");  
        }

        ViewBag.CategoryId = new SelectList(db.Categories, "CategoryId", "CategoryType", ticketsinfo.CategoryId);
        ViewBag.DepartmentId = new SelectList(db.Departments, "DepartmentId", "Name", ticketsinfo.DepartmentId);
        ViewBag.StatusId = new SelectList(db.Status, "StatusId", "status", ticketsinfo.StatusId);
        ViewBag.AssignorId = new SelectList(db.Assignors, "UserId", "FirstName",ticketsinfo.AssignorId );
        ViewBag.RequestorId = new SelectList(db.Requestors, "UserId", "FirstName",ticketsinfo.RequestorId );
        ViewBag.OPSPriorityId = new SelectList(db.OPSPriorities, "PriorityId", "value",ticketsinfo.OPSPriorityId );
        ViewBag.TISMISPriorityId = new SelectList(db.TISMISPriorities, "PriorityId", "value",ticketsinfo.TISMISPriorityId );
        return View (ticketsinfo);
    }
```

Now the correct ids were saved in the categoryID,AssignorId,etc column of TicketInfoes with values taken from database itseif. However none the values corresponding to these ids are populated when I am trying to view the Ticket page. The Index Function is as follows:

```
     public ViewResult Index()
    {
        var ticketsinfoes = db.TicketsInfoes.Include(t => t.category).Include(t => t.AssignedTo).Include(t => t.status).Include(t => t.OPS_Priority).Include(t => t.TISMIS_Priority).Include(t => t.requestor).Include(t => t.assignor);
        return View(ticketsinfoes.ToList());
    }
```

I did some reading on this and found out that Include() is used for eagerloading which populates the related values in the navigational objects of the class. The controller class is named as  TicketsInfoController. Please suggest a solution or explanation of this scenario. Am I missing something here or is it a case of bad database design? Like when I explicitly found the objects from context and set then in create, it saved the correct objects and their foreign key values, do i have to find the exact navigational objects and set them while using include? Please ask any more questions that would be required for any of you to better understand the scenario, I would be more than happy to help!!

Comment: First this is too much code, next time please only put [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) code of the core problem. Are you asking about, why `TicketsInfo` object  doesn't load its `Category`, `AssignedTo`, `status`, etc ? You have used `Include` when loading `TicketsInfoes`, it should load those references.

Comment: I am really sorry for so much data. Actually was not understanding how to present the problem. Yes I have used Include but that is not loading the Category,AssignedTo,etc. Do i have to explicitly query the data or is there somthing missing in the model POCO class? Please help with a solution.

Comment: When the app in the `Index` action, could you please verify that the `ticketsinfoes` variable has loaded its references, probably to be able to see it, you need to move the `ToList()` after `Include(t => t.assignor)`, then put a breakpoint on `return View(ticketsinfoes);` check whether each of ticket has loaded its references ?

Comment: No, they are not loading the references for navigational objects like category,status for ticketinfoes. However the ticketinfoes is loading the correct CategoryId (Foreign Key for category), StatusId. Also this is because I explicitly assigned the objects by finding them in Create function, which I have pasted above. If those assignements were not made then CategoryId was also some coming as 0.

Comment: So the changes from the UI is successfully submitted to the `Create` action, `ticketsinfo.DepartmentId`, `ticketsinfo.StatusId`, etc based on the selected option on the dropdownlist, **and** the the changes from `Create` action also successfully sent to the database (can you also make sure checking it on the database), **and** the problem is only when loading the `category`, `AssignedTo`, etc ?

Comment: Yes I have checked in TicketInfoes table created by CodeFirst in SQL Server. Correct data with correct CategoryId,StatusId etc is getting save. Problem lies with loading refrences to category,status,etc.

Comment: you have `virtual`, it should enable lazy loading even without the `Include`, try take a single ticket then check the `category`, in the `Index` action do this `var category = db.TicketsInfoes.Find(xx).category;` or `var category = db.TicketsInfoes.Include(x => x.category).First(t => t.Id == xx).category;` then check the variable null or not

Comment: Now the context showed a peculiar behavior. I used your piece of code: $var category = db.TicketsInfoes.Include(x => x.category).First(t => t.TicketID == 1).category;$ When I used this ticketinfoes.categoryId,ticketinfoes.statusId all are coming as 0. When I do not use your code, then the correct categoryId,statusId is populated. Since these ids are 0 it is not able to populate the refernce objects like status,category,etc

Comment: What I feel is there is something wrong with my POCO classes, the way the forignkey attributes are defined. Otherwise on selection of the values from dropdownlist, why do I have to explicitly set the different properties of ticketinfo like category,status by finding from the context. That part of code is there in create function with ** marks. Please check whether that is of any help.

Comment: Your code that is wrapped in `**code**` it's still fine, other than it's unnecessary to have database roundtrip by getting the reference first, you can just assign the id, it works fine, but that's not main problem here, Your POCO classes seems fine, you properly mentioned the `[ForeignKey("status")]`, do you have any configuration other than the classes? How can the statusId is 0, it's just a scalar / primitive property, you said it's saved properly in the database, something not right here

Comment: I had put the ** to highlight the parts I added externally. I do not have any other configuration. I generated everything automatically apart from adding the POCO model classes and adding those few code of lines in Create() function. Also this statusId=0,categoryId=0  is coming only when I used your code, or as a matter of fact any code to do manipulation on ticketinfoes in Index() function. If I use what is autogenerated and then use a breakpoint to view the values in ticketinfoes, all the categoryIds,scalar properties are populating correct values.

Comment: Only the references are causing problems as they are instantiated but not populated with any objects. Can you kindly take the model POCO classes and build a small intranet MVC application in your system, see if the problem gets replicated or not? Sorry to trouble you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, the problem lies in the constructor.

By doing below code, it overrides the proxy that has been set by EF. Try to remove it, and fix any (null exception) error manually.

```
public TicketsInfo()
{
    status=new Status();
    category = new Category();
    AssignedTo=new Department();
    OPS_Priority=new OPSPriority();
    TISMIS_Priority=new TISMISPriority();
    assignor = new Assignor();
    requestor = new Requestor();
}
```

**Edit**

By default, EF enables a proxy that will wrap entity type, something like

`System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.EntityType_23EA867FDFE4E4BC07E87138FCFA5B49265FF1A95977DEAA7244B3FB3736CB32`

And that proxy (with `virtual` keyword)enables the lazy loading for each reference, but the reference is overridden when you re-instantiate it on the constructor.

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592886.aspx) for more explanation about proxy.

Comment: Hey it worked...Thanks a lot...I am really grateful to you!! I was indeed overriding the proxies created by EF by the constructor defined by me. Now even I dont need to set manually the references in Create function manually. Also it solved a referential integrity problem which I was getting when trying to Edit the ticketinfo.category and setting it to some other value. Thanks a lot. Also can you provide some explanation on the Edit part I didnt get that as to why it was coming. The error was:

Comment: A referential integrity constraint violation occurred: The property values that define the referential constraints are not consistent between principal and dependent objects in the relationship

Comment: @Joy, check [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8856588/how-to-update-complex-model-in-asp-net-mvc-3)